# how to access active directory from aurelia app with JS

Tags: typescript, webpack, active-directory, aurelia

Hello I'm working on a SPA app with Aurelia framework and webpack as bundler and using typescript.

I tried to use activedirectory from npm. when accessed it with `var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory')` in ts files, the following error in browser console

```
Uncaught TypeError: unknown stream type "undefined"
    at Logger.addStream (bunyan.js?1f1d:620)
    at eval (bunyan.js?1f1d:470)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at new Logger (bunyan.js?1f1d:469)
    at Function.createLogger (bunyan.js?1f1d:1618)
    at Object.eval (activedirectory.js?6f3e:16)
    at eval (activedirectory.js:1901)
    at Object../node_modules/activedirectory/lib/activedirectory.js (app.62c3df06097be3c3399a.bundle.js:107)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.62c3df06097be3c3399a.bundle.js:20)
    at eval (index.js?988d:1)
    at Object../node_modules/activedirectory/index.js (app.62c3df06097be3c3399a.bundle.js:96)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.62c3df06097be3c3399a.bundle.js:20)
    at App.login (app.ts?066e:7)
    at CallScope.evaluate (aurelia-binding.js?5f98:1493)
    at Listener.callSource (aurelia-binding.js?5f98:5194)
    at Listener.handleEvent (aurelia-binding.js?5f98:5203)
    at HTMLDocument.handleDelegatedEvent (aurelia-binding.js?5f98:3278)
```

Comment: sounds like this package is a node package, ant not a browser one..

Comment: yes it's a node pacakge and when I use it in my aurelia application created with Aurelia cli and webpack as loader and typescript transpiller, I'm getting the error mentioned above in the browser console.

Comment: because its NOT a browser package. it will run only in node (server side)

Comment: I'm new to SPA application development. how to identify if it's a node or browser package. Also, is there a way to access active directory from the client side than from server side.

Comment: the author of the package should specify it somewhere, in your case - the description of the package is `ActiveDirectory for Node`.., due to brwoser security limitation - you cannot access this kind of information from the client side - the only way to go about it will be to create a server that will pass the client the information it needs.